# Ruby on Rails and Jquery: trying to switch characters after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

First post on here, so I apologize if some things are off (how I put in the code, if I'm not including enough, or if my question is too vague).

I am very, very new to RoR, and I'm starting by building a tic tac toe game. I already built it to work on the command line, and now I am trying to make it web-based. I have a clickable board, with X and O images that pop up. This is tied to a form below (which I will make invisible once I have everything working) that registers which player clicked which position.

At the moment, I'm having an issue of trying to switch players after the page is submitted. I am using jQuery for the click. I have each space pop up as "X" when clicked, I just can't figure out how, after the submit, to have the player changed to "O". Should I be doing that through jQuery, or Ruby? And, how would I do that?

To clarify, I realize that my code might not be the cleanest, but at the moment I'm worried more about functionality, and will later make it more presentable.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".square").click(function(){
    //   Gather the position that was clicked
    var number = $(this).data("position");
    // Locate the game form
    var form = $("form");
    // Locate the input field corresponding to that position
    var input = $("input[data-position='" + number + "']");
    // Set the value of that input field to "X" or "O"
    input.val("X");
    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  });
});
```

Ruby:

```
def create
  @game = Game.new(game_params)
  @game.save

  redirect_to @game
end

def update
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  @game.update(game_params)
  redirect_to @game
end

def show
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
end

private
def game_params
  params.require(:game).permit(:player_1, :player_2, moves_attributes: [:player, :id])
end
```

HTML form:

```
<%= nested_form_for @game do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :moves do |move_form| %>
    <p>
      <%= move_form.label :position %><br>
      <%= move_form.text_field :player, data: {position: move_form.object.position} %>
      <%= move_form.hidden_field :id %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

<input type="Submit">
<% end %>
```

HTML game board:

```
<div id="board" align = center>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td data-position="0" class="square <%= class_for_move(0)%>"></td>
```

And it's the same for each one of the 9 squares on the board.

Link to the next blocker for those following: [jQuery .click function is not working without a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914641/jquery-click-function-is-not-working-without-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to keep the current player state somewhere between form submits.

There are a number of ways you can do this. One way (maybe not the best way) is to store the current player in the session hash and set it with each form submit. Something like (in game_controller.rb):

```
def switch_player
session[:current_player] = session[:current_player] == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X'
end
```

Make a call to `switch_player` at the end of your form submit action in the controller

Then just add it to your board (which right now is a `<p>` tag, probably should be a `div`) like:

```
<p id="board" data-current-player: <%=session[:current_player] %> >
  <%= move_form.label :position %><br>
  <%= move_form.text_field :player, data: {position: move_form.object.position} %>
  <%= move_form.hidden_field :id %>
</p>
```

Then you can just pull it out with jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

var currentPlayer = $(#board).data("current-player");

      $(".square").click(function(){
        //   Gather the position that was clicked
        var number = $(this).data("position");
        // Locate the game form
        var form = $("form");
        // Locate the input field corresponding to that position
        var input = $("input[data-position='" + number + "']");
        // Set the value of that input field to "X" or "O"
        input.val(currentPlayer);
        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
      });
    });
```

As an aside, it looks like your practicing with Rails, utilizing CRUD, REST and form updates and the like. This works best with more data intensive applications, where the model represents some table in a database and you use forms to manipulate the models and, thus, the database. I bring this up because a tic-tac-toe game may not be the best domain to get to know basic Rails functionality. Something like a todo list might be more appropriate.

If I could give you a little more unasked advice, I would suggest using something like Sinatra. Tic-tac-toe doesn't really need a database backend, and Sinatra will give you some good exposure to routing, templating, handling URLs, without the overhead of Rails. You could think of it as Rails lite. And much of what you learn there will transfer over when you start working with Rails.

Comment: How would I make the call at the end of my submit? I know how to do that when it's a link_to, but no idea with the input type.

Comment: Whichever action is called when you submit (or render) the form (maybe `update`, it's not obvious to me since your using ryanb's `nested_form_for` gem). Stick the call in the action method in your game controller.

Comment: Every time I try to insert anything but a string ("X" or "O"), the jQuery table becomes unclickable. Same thing is happening, even with all of the above that you suggested set up.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? `currentPlayer` should be a string. `console.log(currentPlayer)` in the Javascript code (after `var currentPlayer`) and see what comes up in the console when you click the `.square` element. ( I don't actually see where you have an element with the class "square" in your view)

Comment: Updated the question, showing where the class square comes from. And, nothing is coming up when I click on any of the squares on the board. The board is actually unclickable only when the `var currentPlayer` is up. If I comment that out,  I can still click the board.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're comfortable with data attributes, you could stash the next symbol in your page somewhere logical, and find it when the form is clicked.

So instead of:

```
input.val("X");
```

You would do:

```
input.val($('#some-id').data('next-symbol'));
```

Looking at your code, it seems like you're basically trusting the browser to send you the right symbols for the entire game every time.  Consider changing this to having the form only submit the position of the selected square, and have more logic in your `Game` class to keep track of who made the move and update the game world accordingly.

I think you'll find everything gets simpler this way, and bonus I can't cheat by changing the underlying DOM and submitting a game where I have all 9 squares filled with X's and none of your O's!