# jQuery .click function is not working without a string

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, click

Link to first question: [Ruby on Rails and Jquery: trying to switch characters after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894466/ruby-on-rails-and-jquery-trying-to-switch-characters-after-submit)

I asked this question yesterday, and got what I believe to be some helpful feedback, but now I am now lost as to what is going wrong. I'm trying to build a tic-tac-toe game in RoR, and at the moment I'm stuck at trying to switch players after the page is submitted.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var currentPlayer = $(#table).data("current-player");

  $(".square").click(function(){
    //   Gather the position that was clicked
    var number = $(this).data("position");
    // Locate the game form
    var form = $("form");
    // Locate the input field corresponding to that position
    var input = $("input[data-position='" + number + "']");
    // Set the value of that input field to "X" or "O"
    input.val(currentPlayer);
    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  });
});
```

Ruby:

```
def update
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  @game.update(game_params)
  switch_player
  redirect_to @game
end

def switch_player
  session[:current_player] = session[:current_player] == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X'
end
```

HTML form:

```
<%= nested_form_for @game do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :moves do |move_form| %>
    <p id="table" data-current-player: <%=session[:current_player] %>>
      <%= move_form.label :position %><br>
      <%= move_form.text_field :player, data: {position: move_form.object.position} %>
      <%= move_form.hidden_field :id %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

<input type="Submit">
<% end %>
```

HTML board (just the first position):

```
<div id="board" align = center>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td data-position="0" class="square <%= class_for_move(0)%>"></td>
```

class_for_move:

```
def class_for_move(number)
  move = @game.moves.find_by(position: number)
  player = move.player
  player.downcase + '_move' unless player.blank?
end
```

With the `var currentPlayer` in the jQuery code, the .click becomes unclickable. But with "X"(or "O", respectively), the click registers and is submitted correctly. But the way this is set up, I was under the impression that `var currentPlayer` should be coming out as a string, which should allow this to be clickable.

Link to next question: [jQuery click not registering which player is clicking. What am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917620/ruby-on-rails-tic-tac-toe-game-jquery-click-not-registering-which-player-is-c)

Comment: You forgot the quotes on the `id`. `$(#table).data("current-player");` has to be `$("#table").data("current-player");`. Always check your console(in Chrome hit `F12`).

Comment: Well, that fixed that problem. But now the cell/form is coming up as blank. And the cell is coming up as `<td data-position="0" class="square "></td>` rather than showing `<td data-position="0" class="square x_move"></td>` or `o_move`. Any idea why that is?

Comment: We don't know what `class_for_move` does, so, nope. :)

Comment: Went ahead and edited the question with class_for_move in it.

Comment: Seems like your `unless player.blank?` is true, so the result from the helper is `nil`, a blank string when placed in the class attribute.

Comment: Previously, when I had an "X" or "O" in the `input.val()` the `player.bank?` came up as false. I'm not sure, within that path of code (starting from the controller, to the form, to the jQuery), where the "X" or "O" is getting lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Javascript error console, that's not valid syntax, you need to quote the id for the table.

```
var currentPlayer = $('#table').data("current-player");
```

Comment: Man, do I feel like a moron now. Now, though, the form/cell is coming up blank. It is not switching from X to O or vice versa.