# jQuery click not registering which player is clicking. What am I missing?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, click

Previous question/answer: [jQuery .click function is not working without a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914641/jquery-click-function-is-not-working-without-a-string)

I am trying to build a tic-tac-toe game through RoR/jQuery/HTML and I can't figure out why the players aren't being registered on the clicks. Previously I was unable to get the `.val` to work at all because `currentPlayer` wasn't a string. But now it is, only it is not showing up as either of the two choices. Not sure where the code is wrong.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var currentPlayer = $("#table").data("current-player");

  $(".square").click(function(){
    //   Gather the position that was clicked
    var number = $(this).data("position");
    // Locate the game form
    var form = $("form");
    // Locate the input field corresponding to that position
    var input = $("input[data-position='" + number + "']");
    // Set the value of that input field to "X" or "O"
    input.val(currentPlayer);
    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  });
});
```

Ruby:

```
def update
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  @game.update(game_params)
  redirect_to @game
  switch_player
end

def switch_player
  session[:current_player] = session[:current_player] == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X'
end
```

HTML form:

```
<%= nested_form_for @game do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :moves do |move_form| %>
    <p id="table" data-current-player: <%=session[:current_player] %>>
      <%= move_form.label :position %><br>
      <%= move_form.text_field :player, data: {position: move_form.object.position} %>
      <%= move_form.hidden_field :id %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

<input type="Submit">
<% end %>
```

HTML table (first cell only):

```
<div id="board" align = center>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td data-position="0" class="square <%= class_for_move(0)%>"></td>
```

Ruby class_for_move:

```
def class_for_move(number)
  move = @game.moves.find_by(position: number)
  player = move.player
  player.downcase + '_move' unless player.blank?
end
```

I feel like, given what is there, it should be working. But when I run the page, and click on a cell, it submits with nothing inside. It comes out as `<td data-position="0" class="square "></td>` when it should be `<td data-position="0" class="square x_move"></td>`, or o_move.

I used `console.log` on `currentPlayer` and it is showing up as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it have something to do with this syntax: `data-current-player: <%=session[:current_player] %>` where it should be `data-current-player='<%=session[:current_player] %>'`?

Comment: Just tried that out, and it didn't seem to make any difference. The console.log that I have for currentPlayer is still showing up as undefined.

Comment: Where do you define `session[:current_player]` initially? All I see is where `switch_player` is called after update. Is it possible you aren't creating an initial value when starting a game?

Comment: You were actually right. I didn't realize you put the `=` in the code, instead of the `:`. It all worked after that. So, thank you. Haha.

Comment: No worries. Its an easy to miss error, especially since it doesn't generate a visible error message.